# jquery-loadmask not working properly in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have used jquery-loadmask plugin on my app, it shows processing animation when ajax call starts and hides animation when call finishes.

It works fine in Firefox and it IE8, if i run call to masking function in developer toolbar it shows animation but in ajax call it doesnt work. Any idea why?

Here is how i am calling it :

`jQuery("#content").mask("Processing....");`

Here is the link to library :

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue with DOM not refreshing in IE that quick. Fixed this by focusing mask div after making call to load it.

Comment: Hi! would you please explain it to me?