# DOM not refreshing in IE that quick

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

[jquery-loadmask not working properly in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422792/jquery-loadmask-not-working-properly-in-ie8)

I got a same problem.
It was issue with DOM not refreshing in IE that quick.

step one,jQuery("#content").mask("Processing....");

step two,ajax.............

step three,jQuery("#content").unmask();

I set a breakpoint on step one.
After I press the debug button [step over]
The mask div shows immediately in firefox,while not in IE and chrome.

Fixed this by focusing mask div after making call to load it???
could you explain more detail ?
some operation like jQuery("#content").focus()??

forgive my bad english.

Comment: If this is only an issue in the debugger, you should know that different browsers choose to refresh the page at different times when stepping through the debugger.  This is an artifact of stepping through the code and not something that affects normal running of the code.

Comment: it is not an issue only in the debugger. After removing the breakpoint, firefox works as I had expected. while in IE, I can't see the mask as if it had never showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE often delays changes on the screen until after the Javascript thread completes. They (Microsoft) feel this is an optimization. After all, the sequence

1. Show mask screen
2. do some work
3. Remove mask screen

accomplishes the same (permanent) screen effects as

1. do some work

**Solution** End the thread by yielding control back to IE itself. Do this by calling `setTimeout` with a 0 ms delay.

1. Show mask screen
2. setTimeout to call next function with 0 ms delay
3. do some work
4. setTimeout to call next function with 0 ms delay
5. Remove mask screen